# How can one understand this isomorphism between fractional ideals and $\bigoplus_{0\neq p\subset R~~\text{prime}} \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. Then the group of fractional ideals of $R$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{0\neq p\subset R~~\text{prime}} \Bbb{Z}$ by the following isomorphism $$\{\text{fractional ideals of R}\}\rightarrow \bigoplus_{0\neq p\subset R~~\text{prime}} \Bbb{Z};~~~~I\mapsto (v(p))_p$$

I think $v(p)$ is different from zero such that $IR_p=p^{v(p)} R_p$.

To be honest I first do not understand what this $v(p)$ is and what id does. I think understanding this would help to understand the map. Then in addition I do not see why this map is useful or for what it could be used because it somehow maps a fractional ideal to some "sequence" of numbers.

Could maybe someone explain this a bit to me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For $R=\mathbb Z$, this is essentially unique factorization. Any rational number $x\in\mathbb Q$ can be written as $\pm p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$ where $e_i\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @KentaS Thanks for your answer, you speak about the equality right?

Comment: @KentaS but where are the $I$ and $R_p$? So I see that one have this unique factorization but in my opinion this comes from the fact that $\Bbb{Z}$ is a UFD

Comment: In general, Dedekind domains have unique factorization for ideals. Here, $I=(x)$, so $IR_{p_i}=(p_i)^{e_i}$ and thus $v_{(p_i)}(x)=e_i$.

Comment: @KentaS Sorry I do not get your comment. I'm not really familiar with this Dedekind domains. Could you maybe explain it again. Why do they have unique factorization for ideals?

Comment: That Dedekind domains have unique factorization for ideals is a nontrivial fact (which is essentially equivalent to the isomorphism you mention). I thought maybe unique factorization is "easier" to think about.

Comment: @KentaS would you mind if we proceed in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137123/discussion-between-have-a-nice-day-and-kenta-s).

Comment: Sure, that's fine.